# button stays clicked when performing long task

Tags: javascript, button, settimeout

I am using a button like so

```
<button id="my_Button"></button>
```

and a status message

```
<span id="loading"></span>
```

When the button is clicked a handler is called like so

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    document.getElementById("iFFT_Button").addEventListener('click', myhandler);
```

then the handler function is

```
function myhandler()
{
    $("#loading").html("performing calc");
    setTimeout(performLongCalculation(),0);
}
```

At the end of the performLongCalculation function the text is cleared ie `$("#loading").html("");`

The problem is that during the long calculation the button remains pressed and the span text is not updated, stepping thought the code every thing works fine, any ideas why its not updating? I would have thought that the click handler would return quickly because of the  the setTimeout function for the long calculation.

Cheers

Dave

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would help to remove the parenthesis after your function call. They shouldn't be needed in your situation.

```
function myhandler() {
    $("#loading").html("performing calc");
    setTimeout(performLongCalculation, 0);
}
```

Comment: That definitely sorted out the problem for Chrome but Firefox hangs when I try this

Comment: This will sound silly, but did you clear your cache on Firefox?

Comment: Also, if you're using jQuery anyway, is there any reason youre using Vanilla javascript for the click event?

Comment: not really, there's mostly jquery in the rest of the code, is there a problem mixing the two?

Comment: Not exactly, but for consistency, it might make the most sense to have it all be jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the call to performLongCalculation in an anonymous function.

```
function myhandler()
{
    $("#loading").html("performing calc");
    setTimeout(function() { performLongCalculation() },0);
}
```

Try setting the timeout to 4ms.

```
setTimeout(performLongCalculation(),4);
```

**https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout**

Comment: or you can do as Lee suggested, by removing the parenthesis.

Comment: This works better, it works fine in Chrome, Firefox (at least) doesn't hang but it doesn't update the text and the button stays pressed